# idiom for save and update methods in grails

Tags: grails, save

Are there in any idioms in grails which help us with saving domain objects ?

For example

i may want to do something like

```
if(candidate.hasErrors || !candidate.save)
{
candidate.errors.each {
        log it
```

}

However i do not want to spread the logic across all the places i do domainObject.save.

I also do not want seperate class like say repo to which I pass this domainObject and put in this logic

Thanks
Sudarshan

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use a helper Class, this is a common practice

Comment: @Miguel: I'd like to understand what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a service method that I've used to validate and save, but log resolved validation messages on failure. It's helpful to use this instead of just `println error` or `log.warn error` since the toString() for error objects is very verbose and you just want to see what would be displayed on the GSP:

```
class MyService {
   def messageSource

   def saveOrUpdate(bean, flush = false) {
      return validate(bean) ? bean.save(flush: flush) : null
   }

   boolean validate(bean) {
      bean.validate()
      if (bean.hasErrors()) {
      if (log.isEnabledFor(Level.WARN)) {
         def message = new StringBuilder(
            "problem ${bean.id ? 'updating' : 'creating'} ${bean.getClass().simpleName}: $bean")
         def locale = Locale.getDefault()
         for (fieldErrors in bean.errors) {
            for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
               message.append("\n\t")
               message.append(messageSource.getMessage(error, locale))
            }
         }
         log.warn message
      }
      bean.discard()
      return false
   }

   return true
}
```

And here's an example in a controller:

```
class MyController {

   def myService

   def actionName = {
      def thing = new Thing(params)
      if (myService.saveOrUpdate(thing)) {
         redirect action: 'show', id: thing.id
      }
      else {
         render view: 'create', model: [thing: thing]
      }
   }
}
```

Edit: It's also possible to add these methods to the MetaClass, e.g. in BootStrap.groovy:

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication
   def messageSource

   def init = { servletContext ->

      for (dc in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
         dc.metaClass.saveOrUpdate = { boolean flush = false ->
            validateWithWarnings() ? delegate.save(flush: flush) : null
         }

         dc.metaClass.validateWithWarnings = { ->
            delegate.validate()
            if (delegate.hasErrors()) {
               def message = new StringBuilder(
                  "problem ${delegate.id ? 'updating' : 'creating'} ${delegate.getClass().simpleName}: $delegate")
               def locale = Locale.getDefault()
               for (fieldErrors in delegate.errors) {
                  for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
                     message.append("\n\t")
                     message.append(messageSource.getMessage(error, locale))
                  }
               }
               log.warn message
               delegate.discard()
               return false
            }

            return true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This depends on a 'log' variable being in scope, which will be true in any Grails artifact. This changes the controller usage slightly:

```
class MyController {

   def actionName = {
      def thing = new Thing(params)
      if (thing.saveOrUpdate()) {
         redirect action: 'show', id: thing.id
      }
      else {
         render view: 'create', model: [thing: thing]
      }
   }
}
```

As a metaclass method it may make more sense to rename it, e.g. `saveWithWarnings()`.

Comment: I am not too convinced about this solution for the following reason. Suppose I have a accountService which performs some logic and then saves the accountDetails.I would need to have some thing like 'code'class AccountService { def commonCrudService  void accountlogic(){.... logic here commonCrudService.saveOrUpdate(account)}} ...... I want to avoid injecting a seperate service into all my other services. I looking for some thing like clever use of closures or hooking into the save method something of those lines